# Plotting pandas vs matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

For a little jupyter notebook widget i tried the following:

```
with output:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(6, 4))
     
# move the toolbar to the bottom
fig.canvas.toolbar_position = 'bottom'
ax.grid(True)  
line, = ax.plot(df.index, init_data, initial_color,)
ax.set_ylabel('CH4_HYD1')
ax.set_ylabel('')
```

But the data gets plotted in a wierd way. When isolating the plotting method and comparing it to the pandas default, the pandas plot displays the data correctly.

```
df['CH4_HYD1'].plot()
```

Pandas plot
[image]

```
plt.plot(['CH4_HYD1'])
```

Wrong plot?
[image]

I would like to use the axis plot method to produce a plot with multiple lines of different features. But I can't find the probably very simple error... What is the difference here?

Comment: Could you upload your DataFrame as well? It seems to be a problem with the indexing.

Comment: What is "the pandas default"? What is your input? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), then edit the question.

Comment: Hey, thanks, there was an error in the indexind, I messed up there. Thanks for the hint! How can i close such a question?

Answer (score -1):

This is a short example of how to plot multiple lines from a DataFrame with matplotlib and with pandas. Essentially, pandas uses matplotlib to do the plots so it shouldn't be different.

[image]

Anyway, I encourage you to look into [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/). This is a great library based on pandas and matplotlib that enables visualizing dataframes easily.

Comment: Hey, thanks, there was an error in the indexind, I messed up there. Thanks for the hint!